# List with different types

Tags: c#, generics, derived

I'm new at the C# thing.... (.net 3.5)

I want a Dictionary to hold two different types of object, one of the type is generic. while iterating through the list, i will call methods like add and clone.
 I have tried it with a base class and subclasses....

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Element{
    }
    class Child1 : Element {
        public Child1 Clone() { return clone; }
    }
    class Child2<T> : Element {
        public Child2<T> Clone() { return clone; }
    }
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Dictionary<string, Element> d = new Dictionary<string, Element>();
            d.Add("c1",  new Child1());
            d.Add("c2s", new Child2<string>());
            d.Add("c2i", new Child2<int>());
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Element> kvp in d) {
                Element e = kvp.Value.Clone();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way or solution for my needs?

Thanks!
Anna

Answer (score 3):

You could make `Clone` either `abstract` or `virtual` on the base-type (`Element`), and `override` it in the derived types, but you can't change the return type when overriding, so it would have to be `Element` (nothing more specific). You *can* redeclare methods (`new`...), but that gets messy, and you can't `override` and `new` a method by the same name/signature in the same type.

But if you're happy for the return type to be `Element`...

```
abstract class Element{
    public abstract Element Clone();
}
class Child1 : Element {
    public override Element Clone() { return /* your code */; }
}
class Child2<T> : Element {
    public override Element Clone() { return /* your code */; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the type of .Value you get out of your dictionary is Element, you need to make sure Element defines all operations it should have, like your Clone method.

I would:

1. Make Clone virtual, and add it to Element (or make Element abstract, and Clone abstract instead of virtual)
2. Override Clone in both Child1 and Child2

This way, the code `kvp.Value.Clone()` would call the right Clone method depending on the object returned from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a class hierarchy *just* for the sake of being able to add different objects to one dictionary though.

If the classes don't have a decent enough hierarchical relationship, you would be better off using an interface like [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx), which is already available in the .NET framework.

Then, simply instantiate your Dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<string, ICloneable> d = new Dictionary<string, ICloneable>();
```

It's more flexible. Creating a hierarchy for the sake of the commonality of being able to perform Clone(), is not the right solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Though I agree with Wim, that implementing `ICloneable` is probably the better solution, rather than trying to enforce a non-existing class hierachy, please be aware that `ICloneable` is considered a "bad API" as it does not specify whether it uses shallow- or deepcopy semantics (see for instance http://pro-thoughts.blogspot.com/2009/02/write-deep-clone-forget-about.html or do a google search for "ICloneable C# bad API"